# custom element: attribute won't update component state

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm new with Web Component and i've a problem when i write a component in html and add an attribute directly in html.
The problem is that the component doesn't trigger the set property function.

Only if i set the attribute or create the component with javascript and add it to the DOM, the set property function works.

I've created a pen to give an example of my problem:

[Go to Pen](https://codepen.io/nobald282/pen/BaBzPKw?editors=1010)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.body.getElementsByTagName('news-article')[1].article = {
    title: 'dynamic value'
  };

  let element = document.createElement('news-article');
  element.article = {
    'title': 'dynamic element'
  };

  document.body.appendChild(element);
})

class NewsArticle extends HTMLElement {

  static get observedAttributes() {
    debugger
    return ['article'];
  }

  constructor() {
    debugger
    super();
    this.root = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
  }

  set article(val) {
    debugger
    this.root.innerHTML = `
      <style>
       :host {
        display: block;
        border: 3px solid #000;
        padding: 15px;
       }

       h2 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
       }
      </style>


      <h2>${val.title}</h2>
     `;
  }

  get article() {
    debugger
    return this.getAttribute('article');
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    debugger
    this.setAttribute(attrName) = JSON.parse(newVal);
  }
}

window.customElements.define('news-article', NewsArticle);
```

```html
<news-article article="{ title: 'static value' }"></news-article>
<news-article></news-article>
```

Comment: See my answer as of why you're getting `"ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side"` console error.

Comment: Perfect, if fix it with this code `eval('newVal = ' + newVal); this[attrName] = newVal;`.
Thanks, but you can explain me why when i have a html tag with a property like in the example in the pen `<news-article article="{title: 'static value'}"></news-article>`, the set property doesn't trigger?

Comment: Added what needed to be fixed in my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setAttribute` takes two arguments, instead you're **assigning** `JSON.parse(newVal)` to whatever `this.setAttribute(attrName)` returns (I assume `undefined`).

```
this.setAttribute(attrName) = JSON.parse(newVal);
```

must be

```
this.setAttribute(attrName, JSON.parse(newVal));
```

On top of that, note that `{ title: 'static value' }` is **not** valid JSON. You cannot use single quotes to quote keys or values. It must be double quotes.

Next, it does not make sense to do `this.setAttribute(attrName, JSON.parse(newVal))` in your `attributeChangedCallback` for two reasons:

1. The attribute is already in the process of being set to that (which is why your `attributeChangedCallback` is being executed)
2. Attributes can only contain `String` values.

Instead, what you want to do is

```
this.article = JSON.parse(newVal);
```

which will trigger your getter (which is what you want, because it's that what really updates your component).

I assume your misunderstanding results from you assuming that custom attributes are automatically synchronized with a same-name property - which is **not the case**.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.body.getElementsByTagName('news-article')[1].article = {
    title: 'dynamic value'
  };

  let element = document.createElement('news-article');
  element.article = {
    'title': 'dynamic element'
  };

  document.body.appendChild(element);
})

class NewsArticle extends HTMLElement {

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['article'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
  }

  set article(val) {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
<style>
  :host {
    display: block;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    padding:    15px;
  }

  h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
</style>


<h2>${val.title}</h2>`;
                    
  }

  get article() {
    return this.getAttribute('article');
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    this.article = JSON.parse(newVal);
  }
}

window.customElements.define('news-article', NewsArticle);
```

```html
<news-article article='{ "title": "static value" }'></news-article>
<news-article></news-article>
<news-article article='{ "title": "static value" }'></news-article>
```

Comment: Hi connexo, thanks, i fix it by the setAttribute but the set property not be trigger anyway

Comment: It's correct to say that `attributeChangedCallback` will be trigger only in the creation of html element if it has some attributes setted?
And that set property will be trigger when i set the property element only by javascript?

Comment: `attributeChangedCallback` is executed for any `observedAttribute` which is on the element when it is upgraded. Note that this happens even before `connectedCallback` is called. Later, `attributeChangedCallback` will be executed whenever anything is assigned to an `observedAttribute` - even if that's the value it already had. `attributeChangedCallback` is also called when  `el.removeAttribute` happens, and also when it does not have the attribute and it becomes added using `setAttribute`.

Comment: So the only way that i have to catch the attribute value changed like `<news-article article="{title: 'static value'}"></news-article>` is with `attributeChangedCallback` ?

Comment: I understood, thank you very much for patience and explanation! :)

Answer (score 3):

@connexo gave an excellent explanation on what is going on with attributes, how to manipulate them and how to extract their values.

I would like to add on his solution by changing the structure slightly.

**Getters and setters:** Use the getters and setters to manipulate the attributes on the element. This way you can change the `article` attribute by using `news-article.article = { title: 'Breaking news' }` to change the property value and the HTML, and use `news-article.article` to get the current value of the `article` attribute.

Because you are observing the `article` attribute it will fire the `attributeChangedCallback` when you change the `article` attribute value has been changed. You should put your logic there that changes everything **but** the attribute's value. In your case, change the `innerHTML` of the Shadow DOM.

```
class NewsArticle extends HTMLElement {

  /**
   * Fire the attributeChangedCallback when the article
   * attribute has been changed.
   */
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['article'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
  }

  /** 
   * Set the article attribute value.
   *
   * This will fire the attributeChangedCallback because
   * 'article' is in the observedAttributes array.
   */
  set article(val) {
    this.setAttribute('article', JSON.stringify(val));
  }

  /** 
   * Gets the current article attribute value.
   */
  get article() {
    return JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('article'));
  }

  /** 
   * Do something when an attribute is changed.
   *
   * In this case change the innerHTML of the shadowRoot
   * when the 'article' attribute has changed.
   */
  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (attrName === 'article') {
      const { title } = JSON.parse(newVal);
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>
          :host {
            display: block;
            border: 3px solid #000;
            padding: 15px;
          }

          h2 {
            text-transform: uppercase;
          }
         </style>
         <h2>${title}</h2>`;
    }
  }

}
```

Credit should go to @connexo for his great work!

Comment: It's debatable which approach works better. Either way, you probably want your getter to return a Javascript object rather than a String (it should return whatever your setter accepts/expects). `return JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('article'));`. Good addition nonetheless!

Comment: *Because you are observing the article **attribute** it will fire the `attributeChangedCallback` when you change the article **property*** -- **No.** You need to create the connection between property and attribute yourself (which your code does in the setter for `article`).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've edited my post with your feedback.  About >It's debatable which approach works better: I like to write my custom elements in this fashion because it resembles how most standard HTMLElements function, like when you would change the `href` property of an `<a>` tag. This would, in my opinion, avoid confusion about the behavior of the custom element.

Comment: I agree if the API offers both way of triggering component updates, the attribute and the property should be kept in sync.